# No module named ‘torchvision.models.utils‘

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

When I use the environment of pytorch=1.10.0, torchvision=0.11.1 to run the code, I run to the statement from torchvision.models.utils import load_state_dict_from_url. The following error will appear when:

```
>>> from torchvision.models.utils import load_state_dict_from_url
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchvision.models.utils'
```

Answer (score 16):

After consulting torchvision's code repository, there is a solution:

Note that this syntax is only for higher versions of PyTorch.

The original code from .utils import load_state_dict_from_url is not applicable.
you cannot import load_state_dict_from_url from .utils.

change .utils to torch.hub can fix the problem.

```
from torch.hub import load_state_dict_from_url
```

This worked for me.